# Transforming a complex SQLAlchemy query into a relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I am trying to build a complex SQLAlchemy relationship.

Because I use imperative mapping and DDD, I would like to define it in the object in the mapper itself.

The example domain has 5 entities :

- Player
- Position
- Contract associates Player and Team, from date_start to date_end (persisted in a Posgresql DATERANGE column)
- Team
- Competition

I am trying to create a relationship between Competition and Player, based on a certain position, so that `competition.goalkeeper` returns the goalkeeper of the winning team.

I have managed to build a query but I am a bit lost on how to define the mapper using the relationship syntax.

### Domain model :

```py
# domain.py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date
from psycopg2.extras import DateRange

@dataclass
class Position:
    position_name: str

@dataclass
class Player:
    position: Position
    player_name: str

@dataclass
class Team:
    team_name: str


class Contract:
    def __init__(
        self,
        player: Player,
        team: Team,
        date_start: date,
        date_end: date
    ):
        self.player = player
        self.team = team
        self.date_start = date_start
        self.date_end = date_end
        self.range_contract = DateRange(date_start, date_end, "[]")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Contract({self.player.player_name}, {self.team.team_name})"

@dataclass
class Competition:
    competition_name: str
    team: Team
    competition_date: date
```

### adapter_orm.py

```py
import domain
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Date
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import DATERANGE
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

metadata = MetaData()
mapper_registry = registry(metadata=metadata)


table_position = Table(
    "tb_position",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("pk_position", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("position_name", String(255)),
)


table_player = Table(
    "tb_player",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("pk_player", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("fk_position", Integer, ForeignKey("tb_position.pk_position")
    Column("player_name", String(255)),
)


table_team = Table(
    "tb_team",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("pk_team", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("team_name", String(255)),
)


table_contract = Table(
    "tb_contract",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("pk_contract", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("fk_player", Integer, ForeignKey("tb_player.pk_player"),
    Column("fk_team", Integer, ForeignKey("tb_team.pk_team"),
    Column("range_contract", DATERANGE),
)


table_competition = Table(
    "tb_competition",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("pk_competition", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("fk_team", Integer, ForeignKey("tb_team.pk_team")),
    Column("competition_name", String),
    Column("competition_date", Date),
)

def mappers():
    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        domain.Position,
        table_position
    )

    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        domain.Contract,
        table_contract,
        properties={
            "player": relationship(domain.Player, backref="contracts"),
            "team": relationship(domain.Team, backref="contracts"),
       },
    )

    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        domain.Player,
        table_player,
        properties={
            "position": relationship(domain.Position, backref="players"),
            "teams": relationship(
                domain.Team,
                secondary="tb_engagement",
                back_populates="players",
                viewonly=True
            ),
       },
    )

    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        domain.Team,
        table_team,
        properties={
            "players": relationship(domain.Player,
             secondary="tb_contract",
             back_populates="teams",
             viewonly=True),
       },
    )

    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
        domain.Competition,
        table_competition,
        properties={
            "team": relationship(domain.Team)
        }
    )
```

### test_mapper.py

```
import domain
from psycopg2.extras import DateRange
from datetime import date

def test_mapper_can_query_goalkeeper_of_competition(session):
    position_name_1="goalkeeper"
    position_name_2="left winger"
    player_1_name = "Fabien Barthez"
    player_1_date_start = date(1994, 5, 25)
    player_1_contract_date_end = date(2006, 7, 9)
    player_2_name = "Hugo Lloris"
    player_2_contract_date_start = date(2008, 11, 19)
    player_2_contract_date_end = date(2022, 11, 30)
    player_3_name = "Manuel Neuer"
    player_3_contract_date_start = date(2009, 6, 9)
    player_3_contract_date_end = date(2024, 11, 30)
    player_4_name = "Kingsley Coman"
    player_4_contract_date_start = date(2015, 11, 5)
    player_4_contract_date_end = date(2025, 11, 5)
    player_5_name = "Gianluigi Donnarrumma"
    player_5_contract_date_start = date(2016, 3, 24)
    player_5_contract_date_end = date(2028, 3, 25)
    position_1 = domain.Position(position_name=position_name_1)
    position_2 = domain.Position(position_name=position_name_2)
    player_1 = domain.Player(player_name=player_1_name,position=position_1)
    player_2 = domain.Player(player_name=player_2_name,position=position_1)
    player_3 = domain.Player(player_name=player_3_name,position=position_1)
    player_4 = domain.Player(player_name=player_4_name,position=position_2)
    player_5 = domain.Player(player_name=player_5_name,position=position_1)
    team_1_name = "Équipe de France de football"
    team_2_name = "Deutsche Fußballnationalmannschaft"
    team_3_name = "Nazionale di calcio dell’Italia"
    team_1 = domaine.Team(team_name=team_1_name)
    team_2 = domaine.Team(team_name=team_2_name)
    team_3 = domaine.Team(team_name=team_3_name)
    range_contract_1 = DateRange(
        player_1_contract_date_start,
        player_1_contract_date_end,
        "[]"
    )
    range_contract_2 = DateRange(
        player_2_contract_date_start,
        player_2_contract_date_end,
        "[]"
    )
    range_contract_3: DateRange(
        player_3_contract_date_start,
        player_3_contract_date_end,
        "[]"
    )
    range_contract_4 = DateRange(
        player_4_contract_date_start,
        player_4_contract_date_end,
        "[]"
    )
    range_contract_5 = DateRange(
         player_5_contract_date_start,
         player_5_contract_date_end,
         "[]"
    )
    contract_1 = domain.Contract(
        player=player_1,
        team=team_1,
        date_start=player_1_contract_date_start,
        date_end=player_1_contract_date_end
    )
    contract_2 = domain.Contract(
        player=player_2,
        team=team_1,
        date_start=player_2_contract_date_start,
        date_end=player_2_contract_date_end
    )
    contract_3 = domain.Contract(
        player=player_3,
        team=team_2,
        date_start=player_3_contract_date_start,
        date_end=player_3_contract_date_end
    )
    contract_4 = domain.Contract(
        player=player_4,
        team=team_1,
        date_start=player_4_contract_date_start,
        date_end=player_4_contract_date_end
    )
    contract_5 = domain.Contract(
        player=player_5,
        team=team_3,
        date_start=player_5_contract_date_start,
        date_end=player_5_contract_date_end
    )
    competition_1_name = "World Cup 1998"
    competition_1_date = date(1998, 7, 12)
    competition_2_name = "World Cup 2006"
    competition_2_date = date(2006, 7, 9)
    competition_3_name = "World Cup 2014"
    competition_3_date = date(2014, 7, 9)
    competition_4_name = "World Cup 2018"
    competition_4_date = date(2018, 7, 9)
    competition_5_name = "Euro 2020"
    competition_5_date = date(2021, 7, 11)
    competition_1 = domain.Competition(
        competition_name=competition_1_name,
        team=team_1,
        competition_date=competition_1_date
    )
    competition_2 = domain.Competition(
        competition_name=competition_2_name,
        team=team_3,
        competition_date=competition_2_date
    )
    competition_3 = domain.Competition(
        competition_name=competition_3_name,
        team=team_2,
        competition_date=competition_3_date
    )
    competition_3 = domain.Competition(
        competition_name=competition_3_name,
        team=team_2, competition_date=competition_3_date
    )
    competition_4 = domain.Competition(
        competition_name=competition_4_name,
        team=team_1,
        competition_date=competition_4_date
    )
    competition_5 = domain.Competition(
        competition_name=competition_5_name,
        team=team_1,
        competition_date=competition_5_date
    )
    session.add_all([
        contract_1, contract_2, contract_3, contract_4,
        contract_5, competition_1, competition_2, competition_3,
        competition_4, competition_5
        ]
    )
    session.commit()
    result = session.query(domain.Player, domain.Competition) \
        .filter(domain.Competition.competition_name == competition_1_name) \
        .join(domain.Team) \
        .join(domain.Contract) \
        .filter(
            domain.Contract.range_contract \
                  .contains(domain.Competition.competition_date)
        ) \
        .join(domain.Player) \
        .join(domain.Position) \
        .filter(domain.Position.position_name == 'goalkeeper').first()
    assert result.Player == player_1
```

This test passes.

The SQL statement produced by SQLAlchemy:

```sql
SELECT
  tb_competition.pk_competition,
  tb_competition.fk_team,
  tb_competition.competition_name,
  tb_competition.competition_date, 
  
  tb_player.pk_player,
  tb_player.fk_position,
  tb_player.player_name

FROM tb_competition
JOIN tb_team ON tb_team.pk_team = tb_competition.fk_team
JOIN tb_contract ON tb_team.pk_team = tb_contract.fk_team
JOIN tb_player ON tb_player.pk_player = tb_contract.fk_player
JOIN tb_position ON tb_position.pk_position = tb_player.fk_position
WHERE
  tb_competition.competition_name = :competition_name_1
AND
  (tb_contract.range_contract @> tb_competition.competition_date)
AND
  tb_position.position_name = :position_name_1
```

This SQL statement fits my needs, except that I don’t need the information regarding the competition, just the player so as to map it directly.

### Question

How can I transform the query into a relationship, so that a simple :

`competition.goalkeeper` returns the goalkeeper of the winning team ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem by:

- visualizing the association table (tb_contract) as being in the middle of the relationship
- defining the left side of the relation on primaryjoin,
  which links competition to the contracts of the winning team
- defining the right side of the relation on secondary join, which links contracts to the player.

I could not test its performance yet, but I have preventively activated the innerjoin parameter so as to only load the relevant objects.

```py
mapper_registry.map_imperatively(
    domain.Competition,
    table_competition,
    properties={
        "team": relationship(domain.Team),
        "goalkeeper": relationship(domain.Player,
            innerjoin=True,
            secondary="tb_contract",
            primaryjoin="and_(" + \
                ",".join([
                    "(Competition.fk_team==tb_team.c.pk_team)",
                    "(Team.pk_team==tb_contract.c.fk_team)",
                    "(tb_contract.c.range_contract.contains(Competition.competition_date))"
                    ]) + ")",
            secondaryjoin="and_(" + \
                ",".join([
                    "(tb_contract.c.fk_player==tb_player.c.pk_player)",
                    "(tb_player.c.fk_position==tb_position.c.pk_position)",
                    "(tb_position.c.position_name=='goalkeeper')" 
                    ]) + ")",
            uselist=False,
            viewonly=True
        ),
    }
)
```

### Side-note

The SQLAlchemy documentation on [composite secondary join](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#composite-secondary-joins) features the [string litteral concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation).

```py
relationship("D",
                secondary="join(B, D, B.d_id == D.id)."
                            "join(C, C.d_id == D.id)",
                primaryjoin="and_(A.b_id == B.id, A.id == C.a_id)",
                secondaryjoin="D.id == B.d_id",
                uselist=False,
                viewonly=True
                )
```

but strangely I could not use it as it raised `"SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument"`, hence the usage of `",".join([...])`.